# Limit Number of Times JButton can be clicked?

Tags: java, jbutton, dice

I have a dice program in Java that roll 5 dice by clicking a "Roll" button.

I am trying to make the button so that after it is clicked 3 times, it is disables and can not be clicked unless it is closed and re-opened.

Thank you!

```
topPanel.add(button1);
int i = 0;
button1.setToolTipText("Click this button to roll the dice.");
button1.setForeground(Color.red);
button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button1.setFocusPainted(false);
button1.setBorderPainted(false);
if (i >= 3) {
  button1.setEnabled(false);
} else {

  i++;
}
button1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 25));
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          die1.roll();
          die1.draw(dk);
          die2.roll();
          die2.draw(dk);
          die3.roll();
          die3.draw(dk);
          die4.roll();
          die4.draw(dk);
          die5.roll();
          die5.draw(dk);
```

Comment: use a variable and if condition

Comment: How would I do that? I was having trouble figuring out where I would put the code and what it would contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a variable and if condition
declare variable outside

```
int i=0;
```

inside button action performed event

```
if(i>=3){
  button.setEnabled(false);
}else{
  // do anything
}
i++;
```

move code outside of event

```
    int i = 0;

    topPanel.add(button1);
    button1.setToolTipText("Click this button to roll the dice.");
    button1.setForeground(Color.red);
    button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button1.setFocusPainted(false);
    button1.setBorderPainted(false);

    button1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 25));
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

if (i >= 3) {
      button1.setEnabled(false);
    } else {

              die1.roll();
              die1.draw(dk);
              die2.roll();
              die2.draw(dk);
              die3.roll();
              die3.draw(dk);
              die4.roll();
              die4.draw(dk);
              die5.roll();
              die5.draw(dk);
    }
i++;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but the button is still working more than 3 times.

Comment: I have edited the post with the part of the code I use the button for

Comment: @JohnClark updated .but move int i to class area.and if you can provide ur full code .post it in external site and link to it

Comment: Figured it out, put in the int in my main die class and then put the code you gave me above in and it works. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question about this program as well, is there anyway I can get ahold of you other than here for help?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable in your class body,

int counter = 0;

//In your button click event

```
counter = counter + 1;


 if((counter > 0) && (counter < 3){
```

// your program logic comes here

```
}

if(counter >= 3){

 button.setEnabled = false;

 Toast.makeText(activityname,"Restart the game", TOAST.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make a counter. A variable with the start value zero that increments every time one clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to count how many times that button has been pressed.
You create you variable where has int.

Inside the button listener you increments that variable by 1 (or whatever you want)

Finally you put a condition to disable the button when the counter arrives to the number that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a counter initialized to zero and incremented inside the actionListener for the button. After every time the button is clicked check to see if the counter value is less than your predetermined limit. If it reaches the limit call setEnabled(false) on the button object.